# MySQL: Increment numerical PK from one point forward

Tags: primary-key, increment

I have a table with a primary key with subsequent values 1,2,3,4,... 1035
I want to insert a new value somewhere in this sequence and increment all values above the said value (actually, the order would be the other way round).

Obviously, I get an error with a simple statement like

```
    UPDATE Table
    SET primary_id=primary_id+1
    WHERE primary_id > 501
```

because primary_id 502 is incremented to 503, and 503 already exists.
It seems a very basic question, but I don't remember how to do it.
The table is in MySQL, but I don't think this really matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a backup of your table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE backup LIKE table;
INSERT INTO backup SELECT * FROM table;
```

Then, you can run the following queries:

```
-- remove auto_increment attribute and unique constraint
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY id INT NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY;

-- your original query
UPDATE table SET id = (id+1) WHERE id > 501;

-- re-add the primary key
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

If results are OK, remove the backup:

```
DROP TABLE backup;
```

Comment: So, the thing to do is (1) drop that column as primary key, (2) do the incrementation, and (3) reinstate the column as primary key. It worked flawlessly. Thank you.